# SQL Left Join unindexed table and get one match only for better performance

Tags: sql, sqlperformance

I have table A and table B

Table A

```
date       | id | content
--------------------------
2023-12-02 | 1  | a 
....
```

Table B

```
date       | id | size
--------------------------
2023-12-02 | 1  | 10  
2023-12-02 | 1  | 11 
....
```

I want table A to left join table B on `id`, and return the value of `size` in **any** row. So both of the following are acceptable

```
date       | id | content | size
------------------------------------
2023-12-02 | 1  | a       | 10
```

or

```
date       | id | content | size
------------------------------------
2023-12-02 | 1  | a       | 11
```

My question is that, while A is partitioned on `date` and uses `id` as index, b is partitioned on `date` and **without** any `index`. So joining with table b is slow if I use a naive left join.

```
SELECT A.*, B.size 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = b.id
WHERE A.date = '2023-12-02'
  AND B.date = '2023-12-02'
```

Is there anyway I can write the query so it will execute faster?

Comment: If you add a tag for your specific DBMS, such as \[sql-server\], \[oracle\], \[mysql\], etc., you will reach a larger audience including those who specialize in the specific DBMS you are working on.

Comment: Your WHERE clause turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER one .

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a specific DBMS reference in your question, I am going to answer for SQL server. This answer might be applicable to other DBMS's.

To select the *best matching row* from another table, you can use the `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...)` pattern. In your case, since you don't care about which record is selected, you can drop the order-by.

A `CROSS APPLY` is like a join to a subselect. If you want to allow for a no-matching-records case, you can use an `OUTER APPLY` which is like a left-join.

Your query would then become:

```
SELECT A.*, B1.size
FROM A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM B
    WHERE B.id = A.id
    AND B.date = '2023-12-02'  -- Or possibly B.date = A.date
    -- ORDER BY intentionally omitted
) B1
WHERE A.date = '2023-12-02'
```

Of course this probably still depends on having an index (or partition/index combination) on B(date, id). The obvious fix is to add a supporting index. (You didn't mention why you haven't done so.)

If you have many rows in A and are looking up just as many corresponding rows in B, you could preprocess the contents of B to eliminate all but one row per id/date combination. This could be done with a subselect or *common table expression* (CTE) that uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` *window function*, removes excess rows, and then feeds the main join.

Something like:

```
SELECT A.*, B1.size
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT BN.*
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.id, B.date /*Order-by omitted*/) AS RowNum
        FROM B
    ) BN
    WHERE BN.RowNum = 1
) B1
    ON B1.id = A.id
    AND B1.date = '2023-12-02'  -- Or possibly B.date = A.date
WHERE A.date = '2023-12-02'
```

Feeding the subselect contents into a #temp table and adding an index on that #temp table may also be an option.